# Setting default firefox preferences

Tags: firefox, selenium, configuration, mozilla

Our continuous integration process uses Selenium, and twice in the last few months it has been knocked out of action thanks to firefox updating itself (either on developer machines or the CI server).

We have therefore installed the previous firefox version alongside the later one (this time in a directory called firefox-16), until Selenium catches up.

The problem is, the app.update.auto setting (in about:config) is set to true by default - meaning that sooner or later it will update itself to 17 and selenium will break.  We therefore installed an all-no-update.js file in the `/usr/lib/firefox-16/defaults/pref` folder containing

```
user_pref("app.update.auto", false);
```

which ([according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)) should override any other values.  Unfortunately it doesn't work - the about:config page still shows auto-update as `app.update.auto` as true.  [This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Preferences#Default_preferences) says:

> All Mozilla-based applications read (application directory)/defaults/preferences/*.js

but unfortunately that doesn't work either - the value stays unchanged.

I've trawled the Bugzilla database but can't find anything relevant (other than the fact that an all.js file gets deleted by an upgrade so be sure to use all-***.js file).

Does anyone know enough about the workings of Mozilla Firefox to tell me how to set this preference value? (please don't say "click on the about:config page" - it needs to be automatically to ensure the build is repeatable and stable).

Thanks, James

---

Edit:
 Sorry if the above isn't clear: I can create default preferences, for newly created profiles, just fine.  But as users already have a profile this won't have any effect.  I could possibly create a new profile on every machine, for every user, that has this setting disabled - but it is a lot of overhead.   Sysadmins all over the world must be using this functionality somehow, surely: a way to override a given preference with a centrally-set one?

Comment: Tools->Options->Advanced->Update tab -> 'Never check for updates'  radiobutton. This will turn off all the updates.

Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes I know how to do it manually thank you - what I need is to know how to do it automatically (i.e. using a file or script that is deployed along with the firefox binaries) so that it is repeatable and consistent.  The method(s) described on the two links I included (add an overriding prefs file) would be perfect - if they worked.

Comment: btw - in ubunutu firefox the tab you describe doesn't allow you to turn off auto updates - Canonical have hidden it in their distribution version for some reason, hence my reference to about:config, in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Why can't you use browser profiles ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is using `user_pref()` function - as the name already says, this one is reserved for user's preferences (in user's profile), default preferences should use `pref()` instead.

You also have to consider that whatever you put into this directory are *default* preferences, they can be overridden in the browser profile (in the file `prefs.js` there). If you aren't using a clean profile the preference can already be set there and the default won't have any effect then.

For reference: [A brief guide to Mozilla preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but you'll note from my question that I already reference the "A brief guide to Mozilla preferences" link that you provided.  It is that page that specifies all-cyz.js as the file to put overriding preferences in.  I am able to create a default preference for NEW profiles just fine, what I want is to set an override preference to be applied when this particular binary is started (as described on the MDN link).  I will edit the question in case this is unclear.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1180316: You got it wrong. The preferences in the application directory define the default values - the values that are used if nothing is set in the user profile. The user can override any of the defaults.

Comment: You may well be correct Wladimir, but I quote from the link you posted: "Because default pref files are loaded in reverse alphabetical order, all.js will be loaded near the end, preventing administrator values from being overridden".  This is the behaviour that I'm looking for, if it indeed exists.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN: [Enterprise Deployment (Configuration)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment#Configuration)

> Some config items require `lockPref` to be set, such as `app.update.enabled`.  It will not work if it set with just `pref`.

Suspect this may apply to `app.update.auto` as well.  Although I can find no obvious (i.e. named *update*) configuration option in `about:config` that is specific to any given add-on.  So I don't even know if the per-add-on setting is a pref?